# iOS - Assigning to an iVar in the designated initializer result in a nil iVar

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I facing a really weird issue.
Let's say I have my subclass of UIViewController with it's initializer :

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
managedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        self.managedObjectContext = context;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Here's how I declare self.managedObjectContext :

```
@interface identificationViewController ()
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
//...
@end
```

And then synthesize

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext = _managedObjectContext;
```

Finally in the AppDelegate I do this :

```
identificationViewController *identificationVC = [[identificationViewController 
alloc]    initWithNibName:@"identificationViewController" bundle:nil     
managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

self.window.rootViewController = identificationVC;
[identificationVC release];
```

When I debug the "init.." in the identificationViewController, the parameter context is different from nil but just after the =, self.managedObjectContext still equals nil !!

I don't understand why. Do you have an idea ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT :** I declared the managedObjectContext in the .m not the .h

Comment: to determine if it's null or not, did you print it out in gdb or did you just look at the values in the debugger? We've found that it often takes some time to update the values - "po"ing them in gdb ist much better (right click on the variable and "print description" will do the job)

Comment: Do make sure to capitalize your classes. Naming and capitalization matter a lot in Cocoa.

Comment: Is `self` non-nil at the `if (self)` line?

Comment: @Rob Napier yeah self is non-nil. If I had a breakpoint in the if it will break.

Comment: @LordT I printed it. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: Almost certainly, there is something here that you're not describing. The most likely is an incorrect implementation of `setManagedObjectContext:`.

Comment: @RobNapier I didn't override the setter or the getter of the ivar. So that's why I'm surprise !

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in XCode 4.3. Even if the Variables View or the print tells you your iVar = 0x00000000 @"nil", it's not the case. If you use NSLog(@"%@") to echo your ivar, it will show you exactly the content.